# How to self-join a table with a range of values from both sides?

Tags: sql

There is a table called `teachers` with details of teachers with columns `teacher_id`, `role_code`, `visit_tutor` and `class_code`.  A teacher is a regular teacher of a class if `role_code` is `'CT'` and `visit_tutor` is `null`. He is a visiting teacher of a class if `visit_tutor` is not `null`.

How to get the list of `teacher_id`s of teachers who are regular teachers of class with `class_code` `'AA'` and visiting teacher of class  with `class_code` `'BB'`?

The following code is throwing an error because the first subquery is returning multiple rows:

```
select * from teachers where (
   select teacher_id from teachers t1 where t1.role_code='CT' and t1.class_code='AA'
) in (
   select teacher_id from teachers t2 where t2.visit_tutor is not null and t2.class_code='BB'
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how to join...

Try:

```
select t1.*
from teachers t1
inner join teachers t2
on t1.teacher_id = t2.teacher_id
where t1.role_code='CT' and t1.class_code='AA'
and t2.visit_tutor is not null and t2.class_code='BB'
```